# How to switch language dynamically?

Tags: cocoa, osx-leopard

I want to change language of my app then a Button is clicked, but without exit the app, i kown a mothed but is not adapt that is thought creating a new nib and *.strings files, and set the prefenence. I want to change the language dynamically how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### ANSWER from Chris Hanson:

The standard way to localize Cocoa applications is to create separate nibs for each localization, and use *.strings files.  Applications shouldn't have their own localization preferences; these are defined globally by the user in System Preferences.

### As I said above, the user changes the language used by the system using System Preferences.  Your application should not present its own user experience for doing so.

Thanks for Chris Hanson again.